# How can I echo and execute HTML / SVG in rmarkdown without repeating the code?

Tags: javascript, html, r, svg, r-markdown

For teaching purposes I would like to echo and evaluate HTML/SVG in my **rmarkdown** documents. Is there a way to do this without repeating code? This is my current method with code repeats (syntax highlighting is off so ignore that):

````
``` html
<h3>This is my SVG.</h3>
```

<h3>This is my SVG.</h3>   <!-- repeated -->

``` html
<svg width="200" height="100">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" fill="lightblue"></rect>
  <circle cx="75" cy="50" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>
  <circle id="c2" cx="125" cy="50" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>
</svg>
```

<svg width="200" height="100">  <!-- repeated -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" fill="lightblue"></rect>
  <circle cx="75" cy="50" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>
  <circle id="c2" cx="125" cy="50" r="20" fill="blue"></circle>
</svg>

``` javascript
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script> <!-- repeated -->

```{js}
// not repeated: echos and executes
d3.select("circle#c2").attr("fill", "red");
```
````

The rendered page looks like this:
[image: rendered page]

(Note that I don't have this problem with JavaScript using the `{js}` engine, though I don't know how to include attributes in the `<script>` tag without repeating the line.)

Comment: Please read about [groups](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) and [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol) in SVG. Instead of repeating the same code you can re[<use>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use) it

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. I'm repeating the code so I can display it verbatim and also execute it.